# How can I retrieve the restiction base value from an XSDsimpleType through EA scripting tool?

Tags: vbscript, xsd, jscript, enterprise-architect

I'm making a script to export an XSD from its modelization in enterprise architect to an excel file.

So far it's okay though when examining an element stereotyped "XSDSimpleType", I cannot gets its " type".
For instance, once generated to XSD file, I will have this :

how to retrieve this information "xs:restriction base="xs:date"" it through the automation interface ?

Answer (score 1):

The "type" information for an XSDsimpleType is stored in the Genlinks member (string) of the Element structure.